# ggridge plot and labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Is there a way to add q2 and q4  (quantile)values on top right corner in these plots ?

For example

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Species)) +
  stat_density_ridges(quantile_lines = TRUE, quantiles = c(0.025, 0.975), alpha = 0.7)
```

produces this plot below

[image]

What I am hoping for is something like this where the q2, q4 values are displayed on the top right corner.

[image]

Any suggestions or advise is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a data.frame of the text you want to add for each species?  If so, use `geom_text` to add the text at your chosen x location.  You may end up wanting the`nudge_y` argument to move the text on the y axis.

Comment: @ah thanks aosmith that will do it. I saw some examples online on how  to use geom_text with nudge_y parameter. I will try that.